# Making a 3D-solid from RevolutionAxis

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, finite-element-method, mesh, 3d-printing

I have the following 3D-model:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[Sqrt[E^-x (1 + E^x)^2], {x, 0, 4}, 
 RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}]
```

Is there a way to make this model into a solid so that I can export it to let it be printed by a 3D printer. Now it is kind of hollow from the inside but I want it to be filled.

Comment: Radius simplifies to  $ \sqrt {2(1+\cosh x)},\;0<x<4$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Revolve three parametric curves. `{x, f[x]}` , `{0, y}` and `{4, y}`

```
SetOptions[RevolutionPlot3D, Mesh -> False];
f[x_] := Sqrt[E^-x (1 + E^x)^2];
a = RevolutionPlot3D[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 4}, 
   RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Red];
b = RevolutionPlot3D[{0, y}, {y, 0, f[0]}, 
   RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Yellow];
c = RevolutionPlot3D[{4, y}, {y, 0, f[4]}, 
   RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Cyan];
Show[a, b, c, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {0.76, -1.39, 2.98}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to do it using [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) and the finite element method package.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ℛ = 
  ImplicitRegion[y^2 + z^2 <= (Sqrt[E^-x (1 + E^x)^2])^2, {x, y, z}];
(bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[ℛ, {{0, 4}, {-8, 8}, {-8, 
      8}}])["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Boundary element mesh]

One possible advantage of using this approach is that the mesh will likely be free of defects, as shown below:

```
FindMeshDefects[MeshRegion[bmesh]]
```

[image: Find defects]